Checkboxes in Django and JS not working properly
I have a serious problem with checkboxes. I'm creating a ToDo style application and I want it to save the changes (item_done = False or True) when the checkbox is clicked.
I have implemented a JS script to make everything come out "smoothly", I am using jQuery.
Unfortunately the following error appears:
when clicking on the first item in the list, everything works smoothly but when clicking on the second, the change happens in the first and vice versa when clicking on the first the change happens in the second.
I can't to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I have included the code below.
HTML with Django, list of items in task:
   {% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card border-primary mb-3 text-center" style="max-width: 60rem;">
        <div class="card-header bg-transparent ">{{ task.date }}</div>
        {% if task.image %}
        <img src="{{ task.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-header bg-transparent">{{ task.title }}</h3>
          <p class="card-text">{{ task.description }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-header bg-transparent" ><h3>To-do list</h3></div>
        <div class="text-start">
          <br/>
        <ul class="list-group">
        {% if list_items %}
          {% for item in list_items %}
            {% if item.item_done %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="{{ item.id }}" id="un-check-box">
              {{ item.title }}
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ item.id }}" id="check-box">
              {{ item.title }}
            </li>
            {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          <p class="text-center">the task list is empty</p>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
          <br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add new item</button>
        </div>

        <div class="card-header bg-transparent">
        <h3>Notes</h3>
        </div>
        <form>
        <br/>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
          placeholder="type something">
          </textarea>
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>

<script>
// Check if checkbox pressed
$(document).on('click', '#check-box', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'check_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $('#check-box').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)
      document.getElementById("check-box").checked = true;
      location.reload();
    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });
});

// Uncheck boxes
$(document).on('click', '#un-check-box', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'uncheck_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $('#un-check-box').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)
      document.getElementById("un-check-box").checked = false;
      location.reload();
    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });
});


</script>

{% endblock %}

JS code:
   <script>
// Check if checkbox pressed
$(document).on('click', '#check-box', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'check_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $('#check-box').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)
      document.getElementById("check-box").checked = true;
      location.reload();
    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });
});

// Uncheck boxes
$(document).on('click', '#un-check-box', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'uncheck_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $('#un-check-box').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)
      document.getElementById("un-check-box").checked = false;
      location.reload();
    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });
});


</script>

Python views:
def check_boxes(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        item_id = int(request.POST.get('item_id'))
        item = get_object_or_404(ToDoItem, id=item_id)
        item.item_done = True
        item.save()
       
        response = JsonResponse({'item': item.item_done,
                                 'item_id' : item_id
                                 })
    return response

def uncheck_boxes(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        item_id = int(request.POST.get('item_id'))
        item = get_object_or_404(ToDoItem, id=item_id)
        item.item_done = False
        item.save()
        print(item.item_done)

        response = JsonResponse({'item': item.item_done,
                                 'item_id': item_id
                                 })
    return response

Here display task with "to do list". Every item has own id.
def view_task(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
        list_items = ToDoItem.objects.filter(task=task.id)
        if request.user.id == task.task_user.id:
            return render(request, 'view_task.html', {
                'task': task,
                'list_items': list_items
            })
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("No authorisation!"))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.success(request, ("You have to be logged in!"))
        return redirect('login')

Task and ToDoItem model for understanding rest of code.
class Task(models.Model):
    task_user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/task/', blank=True)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str_(self):
        """ return object name"""
        return self.title

class ToDoItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """return object name"""
        return self.title

Please help me, I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it.

Please edit your question to include the rendered html.

@mykaf the question includes the HTML. Do you want a look of the GUI? I don’t know if that is necessary though? I’m not a JQuery fan so carry on :)

{{ item.title }} isn't html. What's the html that is created from the code given, all loops, conditionals, etc evaluated, especially since the error has to do with first vs second iteration.

@mykaf I've edited the query. I 've added code with a view that supports displaying the task with the list

You are creating multiple elements in your page with the same id (either 'check-box' or 'un-check-box') which is most likely where your problem is stemming from. You probably want to give the elements a specific class and then use document.getElementsByClassName to iterate through them. Oh, you're using jQuery ... iirc it's $('.class-name').each()
Either way, give each element a unique ID or no ID. Hope this helps!

Hmm, each item in the list is an object with a separate id...adding value="{{ item.id }} was supposed to iterate each item in the list and depending on whether it is made or not, it was supposed to be check or uncheck. I then wanted JS to react each object relative to its id. So did I code this wrong?

or do you have any idea how can I give each element unique ID in HTML when I use loop? I have added {{ item.id }} to "check-box" and "un-check-box" but JS not reading this.

One way to give each item a unique ID is to use the Django forloop.counter and add that to your ID.

I used {{ forloop.counter }} with the name and JS does not respond at all, and when I give {{ forloop.counter }} alone I get Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # and in the absence of "#" in JS I get TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType' in the terminal.

I have added a new post with the changes in response. For some reason forloop.counter is still not working....

I made a few changes. In the views, I made a logic that handles whether item_done is true or false.
def check_boxes(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        item_id = int(request.POST.get('item_id'))
        item = get_object_or_404(ToDoItem, id=item_id)
        if item.item_done:
            item.item_done = False
            item.save()
        else:
            item.item_done = True
            item.save()

        response = JsonResponse({'item': item.item_done,
                                 'item_id': item_id
                                 })
    return response

In html a changed:
<ul class="list-group">
{% if list_items %}
  {% for item in list_items %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <input type="checkbox" {{ item.item_done|yesno:"checked," }} value="{{ item.id }}"
             class="check-box" id="{{forloop.counter}}">
      {{ item.title }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p class="text-center">the task list is empty</p>
{% endif %}
</ul>

And jQuery:
// check boxes
$('.check-box').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'check_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $(this).val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)
      let checkBox
      //bellow: Uncaught TypeError: checkBox is null
      checkBox = document.getElementById("{{forloop.counter}}")
      if (checkBox.checked === true){
        checkBox.checked = false;
        } else {
        checkBox.checked = true;
        }
      location.reload();

    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });
});

now the program correctly marks if the item is done from the database but does not read the unique id generated by {{forloop.counter}}.
It treats it as empty (I added the error in the JS comment).
I've already looked for solutions to this problem but haven't found one - many people recommend using {{forloop.counter}} but it just doesn't work.
If I use {{forloop.counter}} with some text "checkbox-{{forloop.counter}}"
JS read only {{checkbox}} and treat every element with the same ID (this is the same problem like the last).
What did I skip in the code?

I have found a solution.
It may not be pro (or maybe it is) but it works and has solved quite my problems.
For some reason JS wasn't reading either {{foorloop.counter}} or the id and I was depending on selecting and deselecting a particular checkbox.
Then I realised that the item_id is passed to the json and displayed in the control log so I passed the item value in addition to the item id and then retrieved it from the json using the getElementById method. Further the if else condition and the checkboxes on the page work as I wanted. I also tested on another browser, deleted the history and repeated - it works!
Below the changes:
HTML and Django tags:
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <input class="form-check-input me-1 check-box" type="checkbox" {{ item.item_done|yesno:"checked," }} value="{{ item.id }}"
        id="{{ item.id }}">
      {{ item.title }}
    </li>

jQuery
$('.check-box').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'check_boxes' %}',
    data: {
      item_id: $(this).val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: 'post'
    },

    success: function(json){
      console.log(json)

      let itemId
      itemId = json.item_id
      let checkBox
      checkBox = document.getElementById(itemId)

      if (checkBox.checked === true){
      checkBox.checked = false;
        } else {
      checkBox.checked = true;
        };

      location.reload();

    },

    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){

    }

  });

});

view
def check_boxes(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        item_id = int(request.POST.get('item_id'))
        item = get_object_or_404(ToDoItem, id=item_id)
        if item.item_done:
            item.item_done = False
            item.save()
        else:
            item.item_done = True
            item.save()

        response = JsonResponse({'item': item.item_done,
                                 'item_id': item_id
                                 })
    return response

